# Elastic Search: Search count of field above range

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search as my search engine and I need search documents having count of `images` equals greater than 2 in a specific array field.
I would like to know count of books having this criteria and another query to return all books id for this criteria.
For the example below, I would expected for count 2 and books id: 1234 & 1235
I tried look at the documentation but didn't succeed for can do this.

```
 {
   "_index":"index_book_1",
   "_type":"_doc",
   "_id":"1234",
   "_score":9.987,
   "_source":{
      "title":"Book Name 1",
      "readers":18,
      "images":[
         "s-l640.png",
         "s-l641.png",
         "s-l642.png"
      ],
     "category":"Baby"
   }
 }

 {
   "_index":"index_book_1",
   "_type":"_doc",
   "_id":"1235",
   "_score":9.987,
   "_source":{
      "title":"Book Name 2",
      "readers":20,
      "images":[
         "s-l640.png",
         "s-l641.png"
      ],
     "category":"Baby"
   }
 }

 {
   "_index":"index_book_1",
   "_type":"_doc",
   "_id":"1232",
   "_score":9.987,
   "_source":{
      "title":"Book Name 1",
      "readers":18,
      "images":[
         "s-l640.png"
      ],
     "category":"Baby"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want documents with more than 2 items in the "images" array, the query below works (image must be a keyword type)

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['images.keyword'].size() >= 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got exception
 "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "No field found for [images.keyword] in mapping with types []"